# How to show random gif images with glide library?

Tags: android, animated-gif, android-glide

I want to show random gif images with Glide library .

I have four gif images . Every time i want to show different gif images (out of four gif images) when app is open ?

For single gif image with glide i have used below code-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.dancingbanana).into(imageViewTarget);
}
```

activiy_main

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: use load(...).asGif().into(imageViewTarget);

Comment: Make an array of R.drawables and then shuffle them, then access the first one

Comment: by this i can give only one image But i want to give four different type of gif images

Comment: type of gif images?

Comment: I want gif images as random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an array of drawables within your values directory `res/values/arrays.xml`

```
<array name="gif_drawables">
    <item>@drawable/gif_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/gif_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/gif_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/gif_4</item>
</array>
```

and then simply select it by doing:

```
TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.gif_drawables);
int choice = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(images.getResourceId(choice, R.drawable.gif_1)).asGif().into(imageViewTarget);
images.recycle();
```

Also noted in this answer: [how to select from resources randomly (R.drawable.xxxx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497074/how-to-select-from-resources-randomly-r-drawable-xxxx)

---

What this does:

- Creates an XML array (as you know how many gifs you want)
- Creates a `TypedArray` object with said array.
- It then uses the `Math` class to generate a random integer based on the length of the `TypedArray`.
- With that selection it then gets the resource id based on that position (in this case called `choice`)
- Finally to help memory management, it then recycles the array after use.

---

To expand on my comment:

You should use the [asGif()](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki) function introduced with `Glide 3.0` also.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of drawables:

```
 private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,

    };
```

Then pick image Randomly:

```
Random random = new Random();
int indexToGetImageFrom = random.nextInt(sizeOfYourArray);
```

The above code will generate a random number for you. nextInt method of Random class generates a number between 0(inclusive) and the parameter given (exclusive).

To use in glide library :

Glide.with(this).load(mThumbIds[ i ]).into(imageViewTarget); where i is the indexToGetImageFrom

Every time a new number will be generated and a new imageview will be shown.

Comment: I am using gif images for randomization so that i have used Glide library

Comment: Glide.with(this).load(mThumbIds[ i ]).into(imageViewTarget);   where i is the indexToGetImageFrom .